# 'Unanswered' tab results in question that already has answer

Tags: support, bug, unanswered-questions

I clicked on 'Unanswered' and the first question in the result list had an answer. ?
I saw this behavior in other communities as well.

Comment: ooops.  I just looked more closely and saw the 'Unanswered' has answers but none of those answers were accepted.

Comment: I can't find something to back me up on this but I believe the Unanswered tab contains both questions with no answers and questions with no upvoted answers.

Comment: Yes, that's what I saw in the definition which I found the next day.  I'm embarassed to answer my own question but your comment is the right answer.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed.  This isn't the first time I've seen this confuse somebody (and it confused me when I was new).  You could write what you learned, including the link, in an answer to this question and then accept it, and that way it would be here for the next person.